# On click event doesn't work on iPad/iPhone/Android on dynamically built elements

Tags: javascript, android, ios, dom-events, createelement

This is how I build the DOM:

```
var projectOverlay = document.createElement("div");
projectOverlay.className = "projectOverlay";
projectOverlay.onclick = function(){openSlider($(this))};   
project.appendChild(projectOverlay);
```

So... `openslider(elem)` function works perfectly fine in all browsers except on mobile devices (Android phones, iPhone, iPad etc...) . Is there any other way to bind events to the yet created element or I am doing something wrong here?

[Live example](http://www.wheniamplaying.com/mmrApp/) - click on contact to get projects and then try to click on one of the projects to expand it. Click on About will get you back to the home page. That's still messy, but the web site is still in early development stage...

Comment: I think that ipad will only register click on <a> tag , but i can't test this before Monday, when i get to the office as i don't have an ipad with me atm... Can anyone tell me if i am right? Can't wait the monday... :)

Answer (score 0):

Some phones and browsers do not implement the "onclick" event in JavaScript. You should to work with the more touch friendly events, such as "touchstart", "touchmove" and "touchend".

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events

Comment: so how would you create element and attach a click event using this method? I've tried everything but couldn't see any difference... Still it won't work

Comment: Does there happen anything when using the touchstart method? You should at least get some feedback.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Its working on pc but not on mobile devices. You have a link in my original question...

Comment: When running in a mobile browser emulator, I get
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'refresh' of undefined` on `projects.js:270`
This happens only when I open the site in the browser emulator. If I open the site in desktop mode, and then start emulating, the exception does NOT occur and everything seems to be working as it should. (Try Google Chrome browser emulator)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue in my project. The dynamically created elements were not getting the click events, except on iOS6 (so something might have been fixed there). The work around I have found is to force a transform on the div that contains the dynamically created elements. The div that contains my dynamically created elements did exist when the page loaded. Assuming it has an id attribute with the value "container", the code would be as follows

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.style.webkitTransitionDuration = "0";
container.style.webkitTransform = "translateY(0px)";
```

Then the dynamically created elements under the container were getting click events.

Answer (score 0):

try move the click event binding after appendChild